# winapi: GetUserNameEx(NameSamCompatible, ...): Is the format always the same?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to call [GetUserNameEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724435%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with [NameSamCompatible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724268%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). MSDN says:

> A legacy account name (for example, Engineering\JSmith). The
>   domain-only version includes trailing backslashes (\).

What is the domain-only version? I just want to parse the username but I can't do that unless I'm sure that the format's always the same. I thought it was always in format Engineering\JSmith. Also what's a good default buffer size?

I'd use [GetUserName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724432.aspx) except that I've read it doesn't always return the same casing.

Comment: You don't strictly need to know the buffer size in advance. If your buffer's not big enough, the function will tell you, and that's a situation you should be prepared to handle anyway. Enlarge the buffer and try calling it again.

Comment: I believe by "domain-only version" it means the case where you are using TranslateName to translate the name of the domain rather than the name of a particular object in the domain.  Note that I see no guarantee in the documentation that GetUserNameEx will always return the same casing.

Comment: For the specific case where you're asking for the SAM name, a fixed-size buffer of LM20_UNLEN * 2 + 2 characters should be safe:  LM20_UNLEN for the domain name, 1 for the backslash, LM20_UNLEN for the username, 1 for the terminating null.

Comment: The `LookupAccountSid` function will *probably* return the username with the casing found in the SAM or AD, rather than (for example) the casing used when the user logged in.  You could also try `NetUserGetInfo` to see if it will convert an uncased name into a cased one.  The best solution, if at all possible, is to not depend on the casing.